# ¿Cómo enviar un objeto a un método void c#?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando mandar un objeto a un método `void`, en este caso, quiero mandar un `label.Text` para modificar dicha propiedad y no repetir el mismo código en cada `case` de un `switch`. Ejemplo: en cada case según la variable contCal, mando llamar el método `setCalificacion()` y le mando como parámetro un `label.Text` para posteriormente utilizarlo en el método `void setCalificacion()`

```
 private void txtCalificacion_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCalificacion.Text != "" && txtCalificacion.TextLength == 3)
        {
            contCal = contCal + 1;
            switch (contCal)
            {
                case 1:
                    setCalificacion(a1c1.Text);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setCalificacion(a1c2.Text);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    setCalificacion(a1c3.Text);
                    break;
            }

        }            
    }
```

Y aquí el método void en el que quiero recibir el objeto:
pero no funciona, no lo toma. Esto lo quiero hacer con el fin de no repetir el mismo código porque serán 30 veces las que tendría que repetirlo.

```
private void setCalificacion(object lbl)
    {            
        calificacion = calificacion + Convert.ToDouble(txtCalificacion.Text);
        lbl = calificacion.ToString();
        txtCalificacion.Text = "";
        txtCalificacion.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: No me queda completamente claro el problema que tenes, podrías explicármelo un poco mejor?

Comment: si observas bien en el método void setCalificacion(object lbl), se va a recibir por ejemplo mi objeto a1c1.Text (es un label)...

Comment: y en esta línea  lbl = calificacion.ToString(); el lbl se supone que recibira el objeto para asignarle el valor en su propiedad text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que enviar un `label` en lugar de `label.Text`

Por ejemplo;

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Llamas a la función pasandole el label
        funcion(label1);
    }

    private void funcion(object label)
    {
        //Chequeas si es un label
        if(label.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            //Creas una variable para utilizar 'b' como label
            var b = label as Label;

            //Realizas tus acciones, por ejemplo cambiar el color
            b.BackColor = Color.Red;
            //O modificar el texto.
            b.Text = "Funciono!";

        }
```

Si interprete mal tu problema, porfavor decime! Saludos

Comment: ¡Justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!